# Как присвоить значения объекта в одном методе,значению объекта в другом методе если они одного класса

Tags: c++, объекты, методы

т.е есть

```
file1.h
void func1()
{
  Class ob;
  ob.set();
}
file2.h
void func2()
{
  Class ob2;
  //здесь необходимо присвоить значения объекта ob
}
```

Comment: Классическая ситуация [проблемы XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/176217).

Answer (score 2):

никак, `ob` это локальный временный объект, который будет удалён после вызова `func1` . Разве что можно сделать его глобальным, или вернуть из функции по значению, вот так

```
//file1.h
Class func1()
{
  Class ob;
  ob.set();
  return ob;
}

//file2.h
void func2()
{
  Class ob2 = func1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас объект `ob` не статический, а значит, существует только во время вызова функции `func1` - так значения чего (ну, или кому, потому что ваш комментарий допускает и такую трактовку) присваивать? Если этого чего-то вообще не существует в данный момент?

Как у вас вообще могла возникнуть такая задача? Может, изложите изначальную задачу - скорее всего, она решается как-то иначе... Создается впечатление, что у вас просто [микроскоп треснул](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) :)